# How to alter a specific constraint based on screen size of specific device?

Tags: swift, swift3

I know I can change constraints programmatically and I know I can vary for traits.

Im working with two odd images in image views that I can't seem to line up perfectly in Ib using vary for traits. I only need to programmatically alter one constraint based on if the device is iPhone 6, 6plus, or anything else.

I thought I could do something like this in View did load:

this is giving me an error because I'm not setting up the sizing of the screen properly, I'm attempting to use the numerical point value size of an iPhone 6 in portrait.

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size == (CGSize: 414.width, 736.height) { //change Ib outtled constraint to x

    }
```

am I on the right track? Is there an easier way to alter a single constraint by device?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to check UIScreen, although I tend to use an inequality and a constant and to check width and height independently:

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width <= Constants.iPhone6Width {// change constraint constant here}
```

Remember that on iPad in multitasking mode you can end up with a narrow but tall screen, so you likely want to make any width constraint changes based solely on the width, whether or not you also have a smaller height.  this is also why you want to use an inequality instead of checking for a specific screen size.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How exactly do I set this up as a variable: "Constants.iPhone6Width"

Comment: Make a struct called Constants and stick all of your constants in there.  struct Constants { static let iPhone6Width = CGFloat(375) }